# Show analytic isomorphism has no attracting fixed point

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

Let $f: D\mapsto D$ analytic isomorphism for connected open subset $D \subset \mathbb{C}$. How do we show that $f$ has no attracting fixed point, i.e. $|f'(z)| \ge 1$ when $f(z) = z$?

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ is one-to-one and onto?

Comment: I think would be implied by the fact that $f$ is an analytic isomorphism, unless I'm missing something. I've written it directly into the question now.

Comment: It would indeed, but originally you didn't put that in the question itself.

Comment: Is $D$ bounded? Because $f(z)=z/2$ has attracting fixing point at $0$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is hyperbolic, we can deduce it from the fact that $f$ is an isometry map for the hyperbolic metric on $D$. In other words, we have
\begin{equation*}
\forall z \in D,\ |f'(z)|\rho_{D}(f(z)) = \rho_{D}(z), 
\end{equation*}
where $\rho_D$ denotes the hyperbolic density of $D$.
It is well known that the hyperbolic density is positive. Thus, $f(z) = z$
implies $|f'(z)| = 1$.

If $D$ is not hyperbolic then its boundary contains at most two points. Julian Mejia gives you a counterexample for $D = \mathbb{C}$.

**EDIT**: my counterexample for $\mathbb{C}^{\star}$ was false.

Comment: What is your definition of an “analytic isomorphism”? Unless I am mistaken, $f(z) = 2\sqrt{e} \cdot e^{-1/z}$ is not injective.

Comment: Of course... thanks.